# Keep track of multiple elapsed times in python

Tags: python, dictionary

For the sake of an example, I have defined a dictionary that holds a specific barcode and a datetime.

I want to substract the current time from the time that is in the dictionary, that works for one but I have no clue how I can to this for each of them.

So what I want the program to do is to keep track of the time, when the time reaches 0 then the time is exceeded and an alarm turns on for example. But I want to keep track of all of them in the dictionary.

Here is my current code, for now I kept it pretty simple:

```
from datetime import *
import time

dict = {'619999': '2017-04-22 11:40:00', '0991626': '2017-05-20 11:40:00', '177797': '2017-06-15 11:40:00'}


def check_elapsed_time():
    while True:
        now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        current_time = datetime.strptime(now, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        component_max_time = datetime.strptime(dict['619999'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        elapsed_time = component_max_time - current_time
        time.sleep(1)
        print(elapsed_time)


check_elapsed_time()
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to ***iterate through your dictionary*** and evaluate each of the values. I also added to your code a check that rise an alamr if one of your dictionary entry is reached.

```
from datetime import *
import time

dict = {'619999': '2017-04-22 11:40:00', '0991626': '2017-05-20 11:40:00', '177797': '2017-06-15 11:40:00', '177795': '2017-03-22 14:05:00'}


def check_elapsed_time():
    while True:
        now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        current_time = datetime.strptime(now, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        for key in dict:
          component_max_time = datetime.strptime(dict[key], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
          elapsed_time = component_max_time - current_time
          print(key + " " + str(elapsed_time))
          if component_max_time == current_time:
            print("ALARM!!!")

        time.sleep(1)



check_elapsed_time()
```

**EDIT:** added a test case to your dictionary for today just to test

Comment: This is what I approximately lwas ooking for. Thanks a lot! It seem a lot more simple than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, your algo should trigger something when one of the time in the dict reaches zero i.e, when our time is equal to one of the time in the dict. I recommend you to choose the "first time to reach zero" by finding the minimum one and tracking that alone. 
You can do that by:

```
    # This program works.
    from datetime import *
    import time

    dict = {'619999': '2017-03-22 17:44:40', '0991626': '2017-05-20 11:40:00', '177797': '2017-06-15 11:40:00'}

    def reaches_zero_first():
        times = dict.values()
        first_zero = min(times)
        return first_zero

    def check_elapsed_time(min_time):
        while True:
            now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            current_time = datetime.strptime(now, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

            component_max_time = datetime.strptime(min_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            elapsed_time = component_max_time - current_time
            time.sleep(1)
            print(elapsed_time)
            if(elapsed_time.total_seconds() == 0.0):
                print "Reached"
                break
                # TRIGGER SOMETHING HERE

    first_to_zero = reaches_zero_first()
    check_elapsed_time(first_to_zero)
```

Comment: I want to check each datetime in the dictionary continuously and if any of time reach zero an alarm must sound, but the others that didn't reach zero should keep counting until they reach zero also.

Comment: Okay. I thought you wanted that alarm to happen only once. Sorry my bad.

Comment: You don't need to be sorry, I'm glad you're trying to help! And I know my english isn't perfect.